# Appium iOS test without using Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appium, headless

Is it possible to run iOS appium tests without using real device or iOS simulator? using some sort or headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect by "iOS simulator" you mean Simulator.app.  Simulator.app is just the head to the system, and you can run your tests headless in the simulator using the simctl command line tool.

Eg:

```
xcrun simctl boot <device UDID>
xcrun simctl install <device UDID> /path/to/app/to/install.app
xcrun simctl launch <device UDID> <app identifier>
xcrun simctl spawn <device UDID> /path/to/executable/to/spawn
```